# How to parse a multiline block of text into a dict using a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, dictionary

I have this multi-line text:

```
1. fef w fwe fwe
fewfa 2. fwa f
fwefwfw gw
2 2f 23. f
g gegwg
32. gre34 g3 1. gr
egsg
```

I want to use the number at the beginning of line as the key (use `.` or  as the separation char).
The resultant dict needs to be:

```
{
    "1": "fef w fwe fwe fewfa 2. fwa f fwefwfw gw",
    "2": "2f 23. f g gegwg",
    "32": "gre34 g3 1. gr egsg"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: In a regular expression, `'^'`  matches the start of the string, so that should probably be the first part of the one you need. (From [**Regular Expression Syntax**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in the documentation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(\d+)\.?\s+(.*?)(?=(?:^\d+\.?)|\Z)/gms

 ^                                       assert start of line
    ^                                    capture 1 or more digits
       ^                                 optional literal . 
           ^                             one or more spaces
               ^                         every character including \n  
                    ^                    lookahead to next block start or end                                 
                                     ^   flags M for multiline and S to have 
                                         dot match all
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T9XRbq/1/)

Then you can create the dict like so:

```
>>> dict(re.findall(r'^(\d+)\.?\s+(.*?)(?=(?:^\d+\.?)|\Z)', s, re.M|re.S))
{'1': 'fef w fwe fwe\nfewfa 2. fwa f\nfwefwfw gw\n', '32': 'gre34 g3 1. gr\negsg', '2': '2f 23. f\ng gegwg\n'}
```

Comment: stuck with regex. tried to understand yours. could you please explain more? thanks.

Comment: The regex101 site has the decomposed regex explanation on the side.